# Programmatically create a configurable product and assign the simple product to configurable product in Magento2 product

Tags: php, magento2

This is what I've done so far. The simple and configurable products are created. The problem is I cannot assign the simple product to configurable product.
Here is the code (ids and attributes works with default sample data).

```
    //simple product
    $simple_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $simple_product->setSku('test-simple');
    $simple_product->setName('test name simple');
    $simple_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $simple_product->setSize_general(193); // value id of S size
    $simple_product->setStatus(1);
    $simple_product->setTypeId('simple');
    $simple_product->setPrice(10);
    $simple_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $simple_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
    $simple_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 100 //qty
        )
    );

    $simple_product->save();

    $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
    echo "simple product id: ".$simple_product_id."\n";


    //configurable product
    $configurable_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $configurable_product->setSku('test-configurable');
    $configurable_product->setName('test name configurable');
    $configurable_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $configurable_product->setStatus(1);
    $configurable_product->setTypeId('configurable');
    $configurable_product->setPrice(11);
    $configurable_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $configurable_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
    $configurable_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        )
    );

    $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(152),$configurable_product); //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
    $configurableAttributesData = $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurable_product);

    $configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configurable_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

    $configurableProductsData = array();
    $configurableProductsData[$simple_product_id] = array( //[$simple_product_id] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'S', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '152', //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
            'value_index' => '193', //value of 'S' index of the attribute 'size_general'
            'is_percent'    => 0,
            'pricing_value' => '10',
        )
    );
    $configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);

    $configurable_product->save();

    echo "configurable product id: ".$configurable_product->getId()."\n";
```

Comment: Have you got final solution for it ?

Comment: What should $attributeSetId be?

Answer (score 7):

You can review on API functional test for [creating configurable product](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Api/ProductRepositoryTest.php#L67)

Code should look like:

```
$product = $productFactory->create(['name'=> 'configurable product', ... ]);
$configurableOption = $optionFactory->create([]);
$linkedProduct = $linkFactory->create([]);
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOption);
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->setConfigurableProductLinks($linkedProduct);
$productRepository->save($product)
```

Please note that the API currently **does not generate** simple products, they need to be created in advance.

Comment: For future audiences: This (and the example, separate answer) is the correct way to do it. But it's very important to note the last line. You *must* save through the product repository. Calling `$product->save()` directly will not trigger the configurable data to save (as found in `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Plugin\AroundProductRepositorySave`).

Answer (score 5):

I created example script. All direct usages of ObjectManager should be replaced on DI

```
    $ob = ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepo */
    $attributeRepo =  $ob->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface::class);

    $attribute = $attributeRepo->get('color');  // color should be in default attribute set

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $pr */
    $pr = $ob->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
    $ids = [];
    $values = [];
    foreach($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
        $id = $option->getValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $p */
        $p = $ob->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
        $p->setSku('simple-'. $id);
        $p->setName('Configurable Product option #'. $option->getLabel());
        $p->setPrice(10 + $id);
        $p->setTypeId('simple');
        $p->setCustomAttribute($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $id);
        $p = $pr->save($p);
        $ids[] = $p->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionValueInterface $opVal */
        $opVal =  $ob->create(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionValueInterface::class);
        $opVal->setValueIndex($id);
        $values[] = $opVal;
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $cp */
    $cp = $ob->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
    $cp->setSku('configurable');
    $cp->setName('Configurable product');


    /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterface $option */
    $option = $ob->create(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterface::class);
    $option->setLabel('Product Color');
    $option->setAttributeId($attribute->getAttributeId());
    $option->setValues($values);

    $exteAttrs = $cp->getExtensionAttributes();
    $exteAttrs->setConfigurableProductLinks($ids);
    $exteAttrs->setConfigurableProductOptions([
        $option
    ]);

    $pr->save($cp);
```

see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php as other example

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your solution. But $cp->getExtensionAttributes() is null everytime, no matter what I do&change. For example : "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setConfigurableProductOptions() on null "

Comment: use code like

    $productExtension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($productExtension === null) {
            $productExtension = $this->productExtensionFactory->create();
        }

Comment: @Kandy, please review your answer, it not works because incompleteness. you have to fix `$option->setValues($values)`, but especially you forgot `$cp->setExtensionAttributes($exteAttrs)`.

Comment: You right.
Maybe better to use code from test
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php

Comment: Just a hint for folks wanting to create simple products... configurable products are aggregations of simple products, so the simple product creation code is in here too!

Comment: @KAndy As I see with this code the `setConfigurableProductLinks` / `setConfigurableProductOptions` it overwriting the already existing links and options. Is there a code snippet to merge existing + new product links and product options?

Comment: Found it: `$configurableProductLinks = array_unique(array_merge($product->getExtensionAttributes()->getConfigurableProductLinks(), $cP->getConfigurableProductLinks()));`

Comment: Thank you so much @KAndy .... Your code really worked for me :) ... (Rocking)

Answer (score 1):

The below code works fine for me.

```
/* Associate simple product to configurable */
$associatedProductIds = array($simplProductId1,$simplProductId2,$simplProductId3,$simplProductId4);//Simple Product ids array
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($configProductId); // Load Configurable Product
$attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attributes = array($attributeColorId, $attributeSizeId); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product(list of supper attribute ids what ever belong to that the attribute set under which the configurable product is)
foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $configProductId, 'position' => $position);
    $position++;
    $attributeModel->setData($data);//->save();
}
$product->setTypeId("configurable");
$product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes($attributeSetId);
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
$product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
$product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->save();
```

Comment: It not work. Giving me error that option are not defined

Comment: Giving me same error that option are not defined - @Asish have you solved this problem

Comment: @Asish & Nidhi : yes it worked fine for me and ofcz u hv to declare the options

Comment: @Nidhi no I am not able to solve that.

Comment: @IpsitaRout can you add the code by which we can declare options ?

Comment: Hi @IpsitaRout what is "$attributeSetId" in your code?