# Magento 2 Associate simple product to Configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options

I need to import 40,000 product from xls so that reason I wrote an importer, I already did for magento 1.x but we switch our web site magento 2,
I can create simple and configurable product programatically but I cant associate simple product to configurable product, This is the best documentation I followed,

[Programmatically create a configurable product and assign the simple product to configurable product in Magento2 product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83107/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento2-product)

But I stuck configurable product options always throw an error,

```
Call to a member function getId() on array in .../vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php on line 109
```

Here is my code,

```
$configurableProductOptions = [
[
"attribute_id" =>  137,
"label" => 'size',
"position" => 0,
"values" => [
[
"value_index" =>  333,
],
[
"value_index" =>  334,
]
],
]
];

$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$productExtensionFactory= $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory');
$productExtension = $productExtensionFactory->create();
$productExtension->setConfigurableProductLinks($sipmle_product_ids);
$productExtension->setConfigurableProductOptions([
                                                $configurableProductOptions
                                                 ]);
$product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create(Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

$productRepository->save($product,true);
```

I m totaly sure something wrong in '$configurableProductOptions' tried almost everything but didnt succeed any ideas or anyone can share code to associate simple product as a configurable I can figured out from that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add StockItem extension attribute to your configurable product.

See how Magento developer do it in the test fixture [product_configurable.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php#L57)

Comment: Hi Kandy, Thanks for your time this is That s what I m looking for! I used same code with objectmanager but $optionsFactory = $ObjectManager->create(Factory::class); throws an error, 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options" for "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory" generation does not exist. I really stucked with this I m gonna accept your answer,I m new in here should I open new question for it ?

Comment: Try to use \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterfaceFactory

Comment: Still same I m gonna write new question with more explanation can you check that one for me ?

Comment: Looks like  Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory available only in 2.1 version

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122577/add-configurable-product-magento-2

can u check my new question its more clear, thanks for your time again

Comment: @KAndy The link for the text fixture is no longer available

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Associate simple product to configurable*/

    $associatedProductIds = array($simplProductId);// array of all simple product ids
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($configProductId); // Load Configurable Product
    $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
    $position = 0;
    $attributes = array($attributeColorId, $attributeSizeId); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
    foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
        $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $configProductId, 'position' => $position);
        $position++;
        $attributeModel->setData($data);//->save();
    }
    $product->setTypeId("configurable");
    $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes($attributeSetId);
    $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
    $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
    $product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->save();
```

It worked fine for me.