# Add Configurable Product Magento 2 Programatically

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I m trying to add configurable product programatically magento 2.0.7 this is what I did so far

I used this link which is @Kandy oferred to me:[link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php)

This code throw an error

```
$optionsFactory = $ObjectManager->create(Factory::class);
```

Error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source
>   class "\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options" for
>   "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory"
>   generation does not exist.'

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    /*  use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
    use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup;
    use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory;
    use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
    use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options;
    use \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterfaceFactory;
    include('../../../../app/bootstrap.php');*/

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    //$bootstrap->getInstance()->reinitialize();
    $ObjectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    include('Yasin-magento2-configurable_attribute.php');
    $state = $ObjectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
    $productRepository = $ObjectManager
    ->create(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
    /** @var $installer CategorySetup */
    $installer = $ObjectManager->create(CategorySetup::class);
    /* Create simple products per each option value*/
    /** @var AttributeOptionInterface[] $options */
    $options = $attribute->getOptions();
    $attributeValues = [];
    $attributeSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default');
    $associatedProductIds = [];
    $productIds = [3974,3973];
    array_shift($options); //remove the first option which is empty
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        /** @var $product Product */
        $product = $ObjectManager->create(Product::class);
        $productId = array_shift($productIds);
        $product->setTypeId(Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
        ->setId($productId)
        ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
        ->setWebsiteIds([1])
        ->setFeatured(1)
        ->setName('Configurable Option' . $option->getLabel())
        ->setSku('simple_' . $productId)
        ->setPrice('10.00')
        ->setTestConfigurable($option->getValue())
        ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
        ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
        $product = $productRepository->save($product);
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item $stockItem */
        $stockItem = $ObjectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item');
        $stockItem->load($productId, 'product_id');
        if (!$stockItem->getProductId()) {
            $stockItem->setProductId($productId);
        }
        $stockItem->setUseConfigManageStock(1);
        $stockItem->setQty(1000);
        $stockItem->setIsQtyDecimal(0);
        $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
        $stockItem->save();
        $attributeValues[] = [
        'label' => $option->getLabel(),
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
        'value_index' => $option->getValue(),
        ];
        $associatedProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
    /** @var $product Product */
    $product = $ObjectManager->create(Product::class);
    /** @var Factory $optionsFactory */
    $optionsFactory = $ObjectManager->create(Factory::class);
    $configurableAttributesData = [
    [
    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
    'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
    'position' => '0',
    'values' => $attributeValues,
    ],
    ];
    $configurableOptions = $optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);
    $extensionConfigurableAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
    $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOptions);
    $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductLinks($associatedProductIds);
    $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionConfigurableAttributes);
    // Remove any previously created product with the same id.
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry */
    $registry = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
    $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
    try {
        $productToDelete = $productRepository->getById(1);
        $productRepository->delete($productToDelete);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Nothing to remove";
    }
    $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
    $registry->register('isSecureArea', false);
    $product->setTypeId(Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
    ->setId(1)
    ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
    ->setWebsiteIds([1])
    ->setName('Configurable Product')
    ->setSku('configurable')
    ->setFeatured(1)
    ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
    $productRepository->save($product);
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Code is incomplete. `$attribute` is not set. Could you supply full working code? That would be helpfull (also for future refference)

Comment: it was two years ago.Unfortunately, I do not have the full code anymore sorry bro @Akif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory available only in 2.1 version.

You can replace code

```
$configurableOptions = $optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);
```

with

```
$configurableOptions = [];
foreach ($configurableAttributesData as $itemData) {
    $configurableOptions[] = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterface', $itemData);
}
```

Comment: Thats new error
Fatal error: Call to a member function setConfigurableProductOptions() on null in /home/rugbouti/public_html/staging/yasin/Documentation/Examples/Reader/Yasin-magento2-kandy.php on line 93, I m gonna upgrade magento 2.1 now, if its solve the problem I ll let u know.

Comment: Replace
$extensionConfigurableAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes(); 
with  $extensionConfigurableAttributes = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory')->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface');

Comment: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory::create‌​(), new error looks like best case scenario to upgrade 2.1

Comment: I upgraded 2.1 still have an error Fatal error: Uncaught Exception\CouldNotSaveException: Unable to save product in .../Model/ProductRepository.php:550, vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php(62), when I look AroundProductRepositorySave.php its again $saveOptions

I think this is wrong can u write for me exact format of conf size attribute with sample content.
$attribute->setData [
......
.....
'option' => [
       'value' => ['option_0' => ['Option 1'], 'option_1' => ['Option 2']],
       'order' => ['option_0' => 1, 'option_1' => 2],

Comment: I figured it out but this answer helped me a lot so I accept this, Thank for your time..

Comment: @YasinUzun, can you please post a working code. thanks,

Comment: @YasinUzun can you please post working code, thanks

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive could you please post code here.

Comment: Hi @KAndy could you please help to fix this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697128/magento2-how-to-add-configurable-products-with-multiple-attribute-programatical regarding configurable products.