# Magento 2 - Get configurable product from current product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I can get current product attribute using `$product->getAttributes()`. How can I get the configurable product list and their corresponding attributes programmatically?

Comment: You tried: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83107/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento2-product

Comment: I want to retrieve it, not creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\LinkManagementInterface::getChildren` to get list of child for configurable product and  `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\OptionRepositoryInterface::getList` to get list of attributes that used to create configurable product

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php`, we can see `getConfigurableAttributes($product)` to retrieve the configurable attributes.

**vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Test/Unit/Model/Product/Type/ConfigurableTest.php**

```
/**@var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $_model**/
/**@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product **/

$this->_model->getConfigurableAttributes($product)
```

Comment: I have set the configurable in admin panel. But when I run `$product->getConfigurableAttributes($product)`, it returns empty.

Comment: Magento recomend use Service Layer API. Any other code can be changed/removed