# How to assign simple product to configurable product programatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, programmatically

***I want to know any script where we can assign a simple product to configurable products with just add product Id.***

can anyone give me script for it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83107/programmatically-create-a-configurable-product-and-assign-the-simple-product-to

Comment: Add a row into `catalog_product_relation` ?

Comment: where I need to add that row?