# How to assign a simple product in Configurable Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, magento2.4.5

Hello I am using given below code to add simple product in configurable product.but it is not properly working.

```
$productId = 1; // Configurable Product Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
$attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attributes = array(134, 135); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
$associatedProductIds = array(2,4,5,6); //Product Ids Of Associated Products
foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
    $position++;
    $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
}
$product->setTypeId('configurable'); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
$product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
$product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4); // Setting Attribute Set Id
$product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Please check this link..  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83107/programmatically-create-a-configurable-product-and-assign-the-simple-product-to